# Redux toolkit get access to full state from extra reducers

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

How can I get the full state from the `extraReduces` section?

```
createSlice({
    name: 'foos',
    initialState: {
        foos: [],
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(
            barAction,
            (state, action) => {
                const barId = action.payload.id; // barAction handler, the payload is the bar's id
                const bar = ??? // getStore().bars[barId]

                state.foo[bar.fooId].baz = true;
            }
        );
    },
});
```

I want to manipulate the `Foo` slice from `Bar` action. But the `Bar` action payload is just the id of the `Bar` entity.

How can I retrieve the `Bar` entity from the `Foo` slice if I only have the Bar ID? Is there any way to get the full store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redux slice reducers only have access to their own slice of the state](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers), by definition.

However, we do encourage [multiple reducers responding to the same dispatched action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action).

Comment: I'm aware to those "suggestions" but I don't understand how to balance them. Note that I don't want to **update** two slices' states from one reducer, but update the own slice's state while reading another

Comment: That's the point - you _can't_ access slice B's state from slice A's reducer, read _or_ write. As far as slice A's reducer is concerned, its state is the _only_ state that exists - it can't see anything else.

Comment: So what is the best approach to allow "Allow Many Reducers to Respond to the Same Action". I've thought about 3 options: 
1.Making `barAction`'s payload to contain `barId` and `fooId` (not sure it so good, since the caller can mistakenly use incorrect `fooId`).
2. Wrap the `barAction` as thunk and use the `thunkApi` to dispatch the action from type 1 (this will prevent mistakes but abuse the thunk).
3. Use `store.getStore()` directly in the `foo` reducer as a workaround.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Definitely **do not** call `store.getState()` in a reducer, _ever_!  In fact, Redux will throw an error if you try to do that. As for the other options, that's really up to you.